# Wildfly DefaultJMSConnectionFactory is missing on WAR deployment

Tags: deployment, jboss, wildfly, openscoring

I'm trying to deploy the openscoring.io war file to Wildfly. This is my first attempt and anything with Wildfly so I could be missing something simple.

When deploying / enabling the war I get the following error:

> Unable to modify deployment.
>
> Unexpected HTTP response: 500
>
> Request {
>       "operation" => "deploy",
>       "address" => [("deployment" => "openscoring-webapp-1.2-SNAPSHOT.war")] }
>
> Response
>
> Internal Server Error {
>       "outcome" => "failed",
>       "failure-description" => {"WFLYCTL0180: Services with missing/unavailable dependencies" =>
>   ["jboss.naming.context.java.module.\"openscoring-webapp-1.2-SNAPSHOT\".\"openscoring-webapp-1.2-SNAPSHOT\".DefaultJMSConnectionFactory
>   is missing
>   [jboss.naming.context.java.jboss.DefaultJMSConnectionFactory]"]},
>       "rolled-back" => true }

I've looked through the domain.xml and can see that the DefaultJMSConnectionFactory is there

```
 <entries>
   <entry name="java:/JmsXA"/>
   <!-- Global JNDI entry used to provide a default JMS Connection factory to EE application -->
   <entry name="java:jboss/DefaultJMSConnectionFactory"/>
 </entries>
```

Any ideas on where to go next would really be appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try starting Wildfly using the standalone-full configuration (`./standalone.sh --server-config=standalone-full.xml`). The default configuration contains the web profile only which does not include JMS.

Comment: Do I reason right that the application you're trying to deploy is taken from here: https://github.com/jpmml/openscoring ? If so, it deployed to Wildfly on my machine with no fuss, in either web and full profile...

Comment: Thanks for the help. I put wildfly on my laptop and everything works fine. I'll work with my admins to figure out what's going on with their instance.